# how to access passed value from widget in initializer flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, widget

I am getting imageUrl from another page. and I want to use the "imageUrl" inside of "theimage" but I cannot access it. I am facing this error.

The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

```
class ProductCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  ProductCard(
      {this.imageUrl,});

  @override
  State<ProductCard> createState() => _ProductCardState();
}

class _ProductCardState extends State<ProductCard> {

  // I can not access widget.imageUrl in here
    final theImage = Image.network("${widget.imageUrl}", fit: BoxFit.cover);

    /// Did Change Dependencies
    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
      precacheImage(theImage.image, context);
      super.didChangeDependencies();
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
            child:theImage;
            );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using named constructor `ProductCard` make `imageUrl` required nullable ,or provide default value.

```dart
 const ProductCard(
      {required this.imageUrl,});
```

And use `initState` for initialization.

```dart
  late final Image theImage;

    @override
  void initState() {
      theImage = Image.network("${widget.imageUrl}", fit: BoxFit.cover);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Next remove `;` from end of `theImage` or use `,`.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: theImage);
  }
```